# Insert huge amount of rows with constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to insert a huge amount of rows in a table t1.
I need the ids(created by auto_increment) of the bulk insert statement.

The performance is way too bad when Im trying to insert every row in a single statement and get the id over last_insert_id();

Im using MySQL

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Before the insert, set the current max id to a variable, insert everything, set a 2nd variable with the new max, and then query all values between the two?

Comment: and when it is async?  how to get the last id from bulk insert ?